# Clip for Timestamp (Panic Coda for OS X)?

Tags: macos, text-editors, coda

How can I insert a timestamp using clips in Coda for OSX?

This is the "snippet" in Textmate

```
$`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to use [TextExpander](http://www.smileonmymac.com/TextExpander/download.html).  I prefer this over a single "coda" based solution because it becomes universal.  So to do this in text expander I would simply create a new snippet with the following as the input (It has full date support built in):

```
+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M
```

Save the abbreviation and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for that. I've used another package for that as well. I'm looking for a Coda-based solution, but +1 anyway.